# Spacing on AppBarLayout

Tags: android, layout

Spacing on AppBarLayout and incomplete app bar title

on geny motion virtual mobile is ok

on all my mobiles problem

problem screenshot:

[image: problem screenshot]

on virtual mobile ok screenshot:

[image: on virtual mobile ok]

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the style of the main activity (the one causing the issues) in the manifest, that should do it. You can check the default values when you create a new project using the "Basic Activity" template.

In this case since your layout contains a toolbar you should use the default theme (or a custom one to the same effect): `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"`. Notice that I´m using the default values of the template. The style you need should be something like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

This would be the manifest entry:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

BTW, just in case you havent done it, consider testing with the same API level in all devices (virtual and physical) to get consistent test results.

Hope it helps!